# How to draw a line in a custom view (Retina) with a constant intensity?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview

I want to write a custom drawing view, which should take advantage of the Retina display. I am using a 2019 MacBook Pro. To test the drawing I am just drawing parallel lines with a width of 1px. But the lines show an uneven brightness across the view.

I already tried the conversion from screen coordinates as posted in
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/APIs/APIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH5-SW2

This is the relevant code block from the views draw(...) method

```swift
// fill with a black background
let background: NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath(rect: bounds)
NSColor.black.setFill()
background.fill()

// create a path that displays vertical lines 1px wide
let path: NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath()
let height: CGFloat = self.bounds.height


var xPosition: CGFloat = 0.0
while self.frame.width > xPosition {
    let rect:NSRect = NSRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: 0.5, height: height)
    path.appendRect(rect)
    xPosition += 10.0
}

NSColor.yellow.setFill()
path.fill()
```

The result looks like this picture
[image]
the lines getting lighter und darker again, they should have all the same intensity

Comment: I also tried it with an adapted version on the iPhone, there it displayed it correctly

Comment: Your screen shot example didn't post, or isn't visible, but I'm guessing you're seeing the effects of anti-aliasing.

Comment: This is what I also thought but I didn't find a way disabling it, or what to do about

Comment: That may be an artifact of your display hardware. Also, how is your display resolution configured in System Preferences? Is it scaled to something other than the default?

Comment: No everything is unscaled; it is the default 2560 x 1600 resolution. Also everything else looks crisp, so if it would be a configuration issue, everything else should have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the solution. I was not aware, that an "unscaled" MacBook Pro Monitor that's set to default/unscaled is actually scaled. Apple upscales the screen resolution by the factor 1,125 as default. To see the correct screen you need to choose scaled and get one step down to see the nativ screen resolution. I am still wondering if there are optimisation measures possible to get a better result even on the scaled display other than using wider lines